# how to search for a substring in MongoDB which starts with +

Tags: java, regex, string, mongodb, mongodb-query

From a mongoDB collection I wanted to search the document for which the name field has substring "+Ava"(substring starting with +). Tried it by using regex but it was giving following error:
"errmsg" : **"Regular expression is invalid: nothing to repeat"**

Query made : `db.employees.find({name:{$regex : "+ava", $options: 'i'}})`

Also tried this query but it also gave the same error
`db.employees.find({name:/+ava/})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is a special character, you just need to escape it, like so:

```
db.employees.find({name:/\+ava/})
```

Comment: Tried this db.employees.find({name:{$regex : "\+ava", $options: 'i'}}) but this is still giving error

Comment: if you're using it in a string you need to "double" escape `"\\+ava"` [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ahzHwLwj-oK)

Comment: Is this required for all types of special characters placed anywhere in the substring?

Comment: all special chars should be escaped yes.